# Plotting Grouped Data, grouped by multiple columns in pandas

Tags: pandas, seaborn, data-science

I have a grouped dataframe according to two columns.
Now i want to plot the data of Date vs Confirmed in seaborn.
Is there a good way to do it.

```
grouped_series = cases.groupby(['Country/Region','ObservationDate'])['Confirmed','Deaths','Recovered'].sum()
print(grouped_series)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change aggregatetion for grouping by datetimes only:

```
cases.groupby(['ObservationDate'])['Confirmed'].sum().plot()
```

Or if need summed values per `ObservationDate` and `Country/Region`:

```
cases.groupby(['Country/Region','ObservationDate'])['Confirmed'].sum().unstack(0).plot()
```

Comment: Yes i need the summed values. So your second code plots all the things in a single graph, i want to display Date vs Confirmed for each country in a seperate graph

Comment: @DhruvAggarwal - Do you think `cases.groupby(['Country/Region','ObservationDate'])['Confirmed'].sum().unstack(0).plot(subplots=True)` ?